# Неизвестная переменная в laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

Всем привет.
в albums/add.blade.php есть такой код

```
@foreach($year as $item)
<option>{{ $item->name }} </option>
@endforeach
```

в контроллере код

```
$year = DB::table('year')->orderBy('name', 'desc');
return view('albums.add', ['year' => $year]);
```

А вьюха выдает ошибку:

> undefined variable $year

. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

У вас сейчас в year ссылка на ресурс, сделайте

```
$year = DB::table('year')->orderBy('name', 'desc')->get();
```

И еще для более лучшей читаемости кода можно делать так

```
return view('albums.add')->with(compact('year'));
```

Но это уже так, кому как удобнее